# botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError:

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am writing a script which essentially will create an item within my dynamodb table. I seem to be getting the followi

Am really not sure what am doing wrong , i did follow the boto3 docs. My script is as follows:

```
CLIENT = boto3.client(
'dynamodb',
aws_access_key_id=Env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
aws_secret_access_key=Env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you were missing tablename in items. Try following snippet

```
CLIENT = boto3.client(
'dynamodb',
aws_access_key_id=Env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
aws_secret_access_key=Env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET)


class AWSDynamoUtils:
def __init__(self):
    print('Setup')

@staticmethod
def add_delegate():
    CLIENT.put_item(
        TableName='invitation-table',
        Item={
             invite-dict: { 'M': {
                               "invitation_id": {"S": "199fd741bca3"},
                                "email": {"S": "testmyemail@gmail.com"},
                                "firstName": {"S": "Developer"}, 
                               "lastName": {"S": "Developer"}      
                                  }
                          }
               }

    )

user = AWSDynamoUtils.add_delegate()
```

Comment: TableName is already defined before the Item. Is the table name a string in the snippet you have done ?

Comment: Now it says :

Unknown parameter in Item.cid-dev8-dga-invitation-table: "firstName", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL

Comment: My boto3 version is : 1.9.165

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the type.

```
client.put_item(
    TableName='string',
    Item={
        'string': {
            'S': 'string',
            'N': 'string',
            'B': b'bytes',
            'SS': [
                'string',
            ],
            'NS': [
                'string',
            ],
            'BS': [
                b'bytes',
            ],
            'M': {
                'string': {'... recursive ...'}
            },
            'L': [
                {'... recursive ...'},
            ],
            'NULL': True|False,
            'BOOL': True|False
        }
    }
```

For example,

```
client.put_item(
    TableName='string',
    Item={
        'email': {
            'S': 'testmyemail@gmail.com'
        }
    }
```

See more on the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item).

Comment: Thanks for great explanation @Lamanus. I have updated answer with referred  documentation.@ london2012_dd : please try my updated snippet